# iScroll 4 No Canvas click/tap events when zoomed in

Tags: javascript, events, iscroll4

I have an odd problem that I can't work out - I'm using iScroll 4 to scroll an HTML5 canvas (implemented as below):

```
mapScroll = new iScroll('td_map',  {zoom: true, bounce: false,
                                            hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false,
                                }, 100);
```

The zoom works brilliantly (tested on iPad 2/4), and the canvas items which have tap and click events are firing when the map is not zoomed in. However as soon as the zoom is used (so in iScroll the scale is changed from minZoom of 1) the click events aren't firing or they're not being reached. If I zoom out or double click to reset the zoom back to normal, the events will fire as expected again.

The click event:

```
trainGroup.on("click tap", function(evt) {
    console.log("Hello train!");

});
```

Any ideas as to what's going on would be great :)

Thanks very much,
Becky

EDIT: After much debug logging to work out what was going on where, it looks like the mouse event has the wrong information. It seems that the CSS transform the zoom does on the canvas doesn't update the mouse clicks, so when I think I'm clicking on the object its actually clicking whatever would be on the non-zoomed canvas. I haven't figured out how to update the mouse events with the translated info yet, but at least thats progress :)

Comment: Why is handleClick: false ??

Comment: Ah that's just one of the many things I tried! It doesn't change the behaviour but I've taken that out now :)

Comment: have you tried the zoom on other block level elements like div? Is it the same behavior there?